# css div with the same dimension as the browser less 30 px width and height

Tags: css

I have and I want that div has the same dimensions as the width of the browser less 30px in height and width to give an idea to have a white border. Whenever these divs resize the browser will adjust accordingly.
I did not use the border: 15px solid white because it will create scroll-bars and I do not want

I tried this but it creates also an scroll-bars.

```
<body>
    <div id="background-wrapper">
        <div id="main-wrapper">
           <!-- <img src="bla bla" /> -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

#background-wrapper{
    background-color:#FFF;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#FFF;
}

#main-wrapper{
    background-color:#F00;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:15px;
    left:13px;
}
```

Any Ideas??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not get rid of the `#background-wrapper` element and then do this instead?

```
#main-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    left: 15px;
    right: 15px;
    top: 15px;
    bottom: 15px;
}
```

An example can be found [here](http://jsbin.com/ugawej/2).

Comment: thanks it worked. It was simple. but the second solution didn't work  with margin

Comment: Yeah, I realised that the second solution was in fact wrong, so I removed it soon after.

Answer (score 1):

You could try some padding on your inner div

```
<body>
<div id="background-wrapper">
    <div id="main-wrapper">
       <!-- <img src="bla bla" /> -->
    </div>
</div>
</body>

#background-wrapper{
background-color:#FFF;
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-color:#FFF;
}

#main-wrapper{
background-color:#F00;
position:relative;
float:left;
width:100%;
height:100%;
padding: 30px /*This shouldn't create scrollbars, but provide padding inside your divs*/
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
body {
  background-color: #fff;
}

#main-wrapper {
  margin: 30px;
}
```

No need for *background-wrapper*.

Comment: That doesn't actually do what the OP wanted -- it only expands with content, and doesn't default to the size of the browser viewport.

Comment: Sorry, you're absolutely right. Turns out I didn't really understand the question.